# Customizing the natbib style plainnat

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I am required to use `natbib` for the journal that I want to submit my paper to. I'm using the `plainnat` style since it does everything I need. There are only two issues:

1. If the first authors are the same, I want the references to be listed alphabetically based on the co-authors' last names. It seems like `natbib` automatically looks at the dates if the first authors are the same.
2. If all authors are the same and the date is the same, the references should be listed alphabetically based on the title; `plainnat` doesn't do this for some reason.